# ssh -A stopped working in macOS Sierra and keychain is not unlocked at login

Tags: macos, terminal, password, keychain, ssh

After upgrading, `ssh -A` no longer works. Uncomment `ForwardAgent no` line the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and change `no` to `yes` does not seems to work. This is extremely annoying. In addition, my Mac is password protected.

Previously, after I login, I never needed to enter the password for ssh once I selected something like "unlock keychain for ssh on login", years ago. I don't remember the exact message. I only needed to do it once for every mac I ever owned. However, it now prompts for password when I need to access ssh id_rsa, such as using `git`. I deleted the login item in the keychain, and the next time I restarted, try to use ssh, the password prompts appears again, but no prompt asking me if I want the keychain to remember and unlock the key.

Can anyone help or at least explain what changes are made for ssh in the new OS.

**Edit**
To answer my own question, `ssh-add -K` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Please don't append answer in your question! Instead enter your answer in the box below and hit the "Post Your Answer" button!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the ssh keys are not loaded by default into ssh-agent.

This solved the issue for me:

Edit your ssh config

```
vi ~/.ssh/config
```

Add the following

```
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Find out more information on reddit discussion:
https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/52zn5r/difficulties_with_sshagent_in_macos_sierra/

Answer (score 1):

The answer above works for RSA Keys, but once I had a DSA key, the solution had an additional step.
Add the key using

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Then, edit or create the file ~/.ssh/config with the following content:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

After saving this file it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Sierra is now using OpenSSH 7.0 which has deprecated DSA keys.

If you need to use DSA keys still, add the following to the top of your ~/.ssh/config

```
Host *
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-dss*
```